# R: Loop using different functions depending on previous output

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

I'm new to R and have done a lot of searching for similar questions but couldn't find any that could help me. 
I'm trying to write a code in R that should do the following:
I have a timeframe of 100 time points. I want to use a loop for putting each time point into a linear function, retrieving the output, storing it into a vector und then using the last output for the next time point.
The first function represents a linear increase. I would like the algorithm to use the first function until a certain threshold output is reached (yresult=5), after this, the second function with a linear decrease should be used.
I have written the following code, but somehow it seems not to work - it stores no values in yresult and then plotting obviously fails.
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    tt<-seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
    tt_l <-length(tt)
    yresult<-NULL

    linfunct1 <- function (i, m) {
     m=0.5
     if (i<=1) y=0 else 
        y=m*i+yresult[i-1]}

    linfunct2 <- function (i, m) {
      m=-0.1
      if (i<=1) y=0 else 
        y=m*i+yresult[i-1]}

    for (i in 1:tt_l) {
      yresult [i] <- ifelse (yresult[i-1]<5,linfunct1(i),linfunct2(i))}

    results <-data.frame("Time"=tt, "Results"=yresult)
    plot(yresult~tt, col="red")
```

update:

I successfully wrote a code before, in which the slope of the linear function changes depending on a certain time point (ith entry of tt).
       library(dplyr)
    library(plyr)
    library(ggplot2)

```
tt<-seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
tt_l <-length(tt)
yresult<-NULL
linfunct <- function (i, m) {
  if (i<5) m=0.5 else m=-0.5
  if (i==1) y=0 else 
    y=m*i+yresult[i-1]}

for (i in 1:tt_l) {
  yresult[i]=linfunct(i)}

results <-data.frame("Time"=tt, "Results"=yresult)
plot(yresult~tt, col="red")
```

In this code, yresult can be accessed so I thought it should work in the new code as well.
I wanted to change the "time-based" code so that the slope of the function would depend on my last result and not on the time point, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Update2:

I have updated my code with the following suggestions:

```
    tt<-seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
    tt_l <-length(tt)
    yresult <- rep(0, tt_l)

    linfunct1 <- function (i, m=0.5) {
    m=0.5
    if (i<=1) {
    y=0
    } else {
    y=m*i+yresult[i-1]
    }
    y
    }

    linfunct2 <- function (i, m=-0.1) {
    m=-0.1
    if (i<=1) {
    y=0
    } else {
    y=m*i+yresult[i-1]
    }
    y
    }

    for (i in 2:tt_l) {
    yresult[i] <- ifelse(yresult[i-1]<5, linfunct1(i=i), linfunct2(i=i)               )
    }

    results <-data.frame("Time"=tt, "Results"=yresult)
    plot(yresult~tt, col="red")
```

I would expect an output of yresult that increases until it becomes 5 and then continuously decreases. 
Like this: [graph from code depending on tt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLKZy.png)
What I get is an output of yresult that increases until i=5, then decreases until yresult is lower than 5, then jumps up to a higher value and decreases again until yresult is lower than 5. Then jumps up to an even higher value and so forth. 
Like this: [graph I get from code of second update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL8tn.png)

Comment: `for (i in 1:tt_l) {yresult [i] <- ifelse (yresult[i-1]<5,linfunct1(i),linfunct2(i))}` won't run when `yresult <- NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Your functions need to return a value:

```
linfunct1 <- function (i, m) {
    m=0.5
    if (i<=1) {
        y=0
    } else {
        y=m*i+yresult[i-1]
    }
    y # returning this value
}
```

Does this work for you:

```
tt<-seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 1)
tt_l <-length(tt)
yresult <- rep(0, tt_l)

linfunct1 <- function (i, m=0.5) {
    m=0.5
    if (i<=1) {
        y=0
    } else {
        y=m*i+yresult[i-1]
    }
    y
}

linfunct2 <- function (i, m=-0.1) {
    m=-0.1
    if (i<=1) {
        y=0
    } else {
        y=m*i+yresult[i-1]
    }
    y
}

for (i in 2:tt_l) {
    yresult[i] <- ifelse(yresult[i-1]<5, linfunct1(i=i), linfunct2(i=i) )
}

results <-data.frame("Time"=tt, "Results"=yresult)
plot(yresult~tt, col="red")
```

[image]

Update: You're right, your functions can access the `yresult` object.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I tried to update my function with your suggestions - it works well for a couple of time points, then something weird happens: the values decrease but every view time points it "jumps" to a higher value from which it then decreases. These are the first 10 values which I get in my results:
Time Results
    0     0.0
    1     1.0
    2     2.5
    3     4.5
    4     7.0
    5     6.4
    6     5.7
    7     4.9
    8     9.4
    9     8.4
   10     7.3

Also, I added further information to my question above, maybe this helps?

Comment: I'm sorry how the comment looks. I hope you can figure out this kind of "data frame". First is the timepoint, then comes the value. The first "jump" occurs between timepoints 7 and 8 from 4.9 to 9.4 after that it decreases again.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code, what results you're expecting, and the results you're getting?

Comment: Thanks again, I have made a second update I hope this clarifys.

Comment: I think you're now asking for help with the algorithm, as opposed to help with the R code. If you need help designing an algorithm that produces the output you want, you could consider asking a new question.